# How to avoid redundant case/when in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, case

Based on this simple example table:

```
create table some_data (x integer, y integer);

insert into some_data (x,y) values
(1,1),
(1,2),
(1,1000),
(1,2),
(2,1),
(2,1),
(2,2);
```

I query it trying to sum the values based on particular conditions, like:

```
select
  case when x = 1 then
        sum(case when y = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as counter_x,
        sum(case when y = 2 then 2 else 0 end) as counter_y,
        sum(case when y > 2 then 7 else 0 end) as counter_z,
      end,

  sum(case when x = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as counter_a,
  sum(case when x = 2 and y = 1 then 10 else 0 end) as counter_b,
  sum(case when x = 3 and y = 30 then 400 else 0 end) as counter_c
  from some_data;
```

What I am expecting here is:

```
counter_x | counter_y | counter_z | counter_a | counter_b | counter_c
----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------
1         | 4         | 7         | 4         | 20        | 0
```

However my query doesn't work as the wrapping `case when x = 1` is not allowed.
How can I fix it?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Version postgres 9.5

Comment: cool, I've tried answer both sides of this question. You can't make the schema of the result dependent on the result itself. If that's what you're trying to do. See my answer, and consider clarifying if none of the answers here help you.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a condition for every counter:

```
select
    sum(case when x = 1 and y = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as counter_x,
    sum(case when x = 1 and y = 2 then 2 else 0 end) as counter_y,
    sum(case when x = 1 and y > 2 then 7 else 0 end) as counter_z,
    sum(case when x = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as counter_a,
    sum(case when x = 2 and y = 1 then 10 else 0 end) as counter_b,
    sum(case when x = 3 and y = 30 then 400 else 0 end) as counter_c
from 
    some_data;

counter_x | counter_y | counter_z | counter_a | counter_b | counter_c
--------: | --------: | --------: | --------: | --------: | --------:
        1 |         4 |         7 |         4 |        20 |         0
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2896714e1ebd4f5f615fd8e3ef654353)*

Comment: The problem with that solution is `case when x = 1` is redundant. It may be a redundant function for example (expensive to run).

Answer (score 1):

@McNets answer gives the simplest and probably most cost-effective SQL.

If you're worried about computing `case when x = 1` (let's assume it is `case f(x) = const`) more times than needed, you can, in principle, precompute `x = 1` values in a subquery:

```
SELECT
    sum(case when x1    and y = 1  then 1   end) as counter_x,
    sum(case when x1    and y = 2  then 2   end) as counter_y,
    sum(case when x1    and y > 2  then 7   end) as counter_z,
    sum(case when x1               then 1   end) as counter_a,
    sum(case when x = 2 and y = 1  then 10  end) as counter_b,
    sum(case when x = 3 and y = 30 then 400 end) as counter_c
FROM 
    (
    SELECT
        x, 
        (x = 1) AS x1, -- probably x = 1, or f(x) will only be computed once, but don't count on it
        y
    FROM 
         some_data
    ) AS pre_computed_values ;
```

```
counter_x | counter_y | counter_z | counter_a | counter_b | counter_c
--------: | --------: | --------: | --------: | --------: | --------:
        1 |         4 |         7 |         4 |        20 |      null
```

Whether the database query planner will plan this execution depends a lot on the *cost* associated which whatever the *cost* is for computing `f(x)`, and wheter `f(x)` is `IMMUTABLE` or at least `STABLE` (see [Function Volatility](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html)).

Also, when summing you can skip the `else 0` clauses, if you can have `NULL` as a global response. The default value for a `case when cond then v` is to return `NULL` if `cond` is not met. And (most) aggregation functions, like `SUM` will simply ignore `NULL`s; returning `NULL` if *all* inputs are also `NULLS`. I don't think this saves significant (or any) computing time, but it saves some writing... You just can get you a small difference (`counter_c`).

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=db12425744273e518e057c172c7c5b87)*

Answer (score 0):

> However my query doesn't work as the wrapping case when x = 1 is not allowed. How can I fix it?

You can't make the query schema dependent on the result set.

1. Those counts always have to be there regardless of what x equals.
2. You have to use dynamic sql.

> The problem with that solution is case when x = 1 is redundant. It may be a redundant function for example (expensive to run).

If that's so, if it is redundant then the query planner needs to be smart enough to handle it. You have limited control in a declarative language like SQL. Unfortunately there is no method to compose the aggregates manually like that though you could always [create your own](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html), it's not exactly easy. PostgreSQL will calculate these aggregates in a single table pass though.

## Cleaning up the query

I also agree with McNets in that the CASE should be flattened. However, You can fold this together with `count` and an [aggregate filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html).

```
SELECT
    1   * count(*) FILTER (WHERE x=1 AND y=1)    AS counter_x,
    2   * count(*) FILTER (WHERE x=1 AND y=2)    AS counter_y,
    7   * count(*) FILTER (WHERE x=1 AND y>2)    AS counter_z,
    1   * count(*) FILTER (WHERE x=1)            AS counter_a,
    10  * count(*) FILTER (WHERE x=2 AND y=1)    AS counter_b,
    400 * count(*) FILTER (WHERE x=3 AND y=30)   AS counter_c
from 
    some_data;
```

Alternatively, you can use count without an aggregate filter..

```
400 * count(CASE WHEN x=3 AND y=30 THEN 1 END)
```